# How to make Javascript work in my EJS file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have been trying to figure out this prob of mine for a while now. Please see my code below. I want to compare my password and confirm my password. If it is not equal, then I want my button to be disabled. Then if it matched, then I want the button to be enabled. I'm using ejs template, so it's hard for me to put js inside. I am just a beginner.   like this

[javascript code for disabled and enabled button](https://jsfiddle.net/aelor/F6sEv/324/)

```
 <%- include('partials/header') %>


<%function check_pass() {%>
 <% if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('conpassword').value) {%>
    <%  document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;%>
  <% }else {%>
     <% document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;%>
  <% }%>
 <% }%>


  <div class="login-page">
    <form autocomplete="off" action="/register" method="POST">
      <h1> Sign Up</h1>
      <label for="lastname"> Last Name </label>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="lastname" />

      <label for="firstname"> First Name </label>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="firstname" />

      <label for="email"> Email </label>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="email" name="username" />

    
      <label for="password"> Password </label>
      <input name="password" id="password" type="password" onchange='check_pass()'/>

      <label for="password"> Confirm Password </label>
      <input name="conpassword" id="conpassword" type="password"onchange='check_pass()' />

      <button type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" disabled>>Sign up</button>


    </form>
 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove <% your script %> tag from your script and wrap in tag script HTML, it's like writing in HTML format. For more information (tags EJS) see here: [documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs).

```html
<script>
function check_pass() {
 if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('conpassword').value) {
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
     }else {
     document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
     }
}
check_pass();
</script>
```